# SVN checkout is failing with svn:// protocol but it is working with svn+ssh:// protocol

Tags: linux, apache, svn

1) svn:// - not working
[image]

2) svn+ssh:// - working
[image]I am using linux server with installed apache and tomcat into it and I want to access svn using svn:// protocol

I have installed svn using 'yum install subversion' command
My svn version is - version 1.7.14 (r1542130).

After installation, I can access it using svn+ssh:// protocol but I can't access it using just svn:// protocol.

When I try to access it using svn+ssh:// it keeps me asking for ssh password and it is not asking svn userid and password.

I want to access it using just svn:// protocol with svn userids and passwords.

Things I checked -

1) Svenserve daemon has already been started using command
   svnserve -d -r /webcontent/data/svn_repo

Comment: It smells like a firewall issue to me. Did you open up the svnserve port in your firewall on the server?

Comment: @John - I can telnet 3690 successfully.

Comment: @John - It was blocked at firewall level and it was not running so the changes were not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to use `svn://` you **must** to run **pure** svnserve daemon before
- When you connect with `svn+ssh://` you really connect to host using ssh and run all svn-related tasks inside tunnel.

Comment: Hi, svenserve daemon has already been started using command - svnserve -d -r /webcontent/data/svn_repo

Comment: @HardikDoshi - OK. Check accessibility of svn port (3690) - it can be filtered: jest telnet on this port by hand

Comment: @HardikDoshi - OK, test application-level. `svn ls` from CLI, firewall rules for tortoiseproc (if any) - you got **timeout** in TSVN, you have to find, that was blocked

Comment: Hi, I found that 3690 was blocked at firewall level, and it was not running. Used below commands                                                    1) 'firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3690/tcp --permanent' to open port'                                                                                                  2) 'firewall-cmd --reload'                                                                             3) 'service firewalld start'